# Multitrack Video Does Not Transcode Real Time

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, transcode

Recently this Github page, dedicated to bypassing Nvidia's encode limit, added windows support:
https://github.com/keylase/nvidia-patch/tree/master/win

Up until now I've been encoding my 5 live streams across my GPU and CPU due to the encode limit imposed on consumer Nvidia GPUs, so 2 streams on my GPU and 3 streams on my CPU. But with the help of this patch I can now encode all 5 streams with just my GPU, which go me thinking - as opposed to encoding 5 separate output videos maybe I can encode all streams into 1 file.

It has been pretty difficult to create a command that keeps all 5 separate output files synchronized, due to the nature of segmentation. So I'm thinking that if I do everything in one file I can bypass some of those troubles and simplify my workflow / command. However, I've found that when I try to put everything in one output file I can't transcode real time.

Example command:

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147M -video_size 3840x2160 `
-framerate 60 -pixel_format nv12 -i video="Video (Pro Capture)":audio="ADAT (3+4) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147M -video_size 3840x2160 -framerate 60 -pixel_format nv12 `
-i video="AVerMedia HD Capture GC573 1":audio="Analog (1+2) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147M -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 60 -pixel_format yuv420p `
-i video="Game Capture HD60 Pro (Video) (#01)":audio="Game Capture HD60 Pro (Audio) (#01)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147M -i audio="ADAT (5+6) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147M -i audio="SPDIF/ADAT (1+2) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-c:v h264_nvenc -preset: llhp -pix_fmt nv12 -b:v 288M -minrate 288M -maxrate 288M -bufsize 288M -c:a aac -ar 44100 `
-b:a 384k -vsync 1 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -map 4 `
-f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_format_options max_delay=0 `
C:\Users\djcim\Videos\FFmpeg\FFmpeg%02d.ts
```

The above command does not transcode real time, sits at about .6x speed. However when I simply seperate everything to multiple outputs I transcode real time:

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147.48M -i audio="Analog (1+2) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147.48M -i audio="ADAT (5+6) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -r 25 -f lavfi -rtbufsize 2147.48M -i color=c=black:s=256x120 `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147.48M -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 60 `
-pixel_format yuv420p -i video="Game Capture HD60 Pro (Video) (#01)":audio="Game Capture HD60 Pro (Audio) (#01)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147.48M -video_size 3840x2160 -framerate 60 `
-pixel_format nv12 -i video="Video (Pro Capture)":audio="ADAT (3+4) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147.48M -video_size 3840x2160 -framerate 60 `
-pixel_format nv12 -i video="AVerMedia HD Capture GC573 1":audio="Analog (1+2) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-map 2,0 -map 0 -c:v h264_nvenc -preset: llhp -r 25 -rc-lookahead 25 -pix_fmt nv12 -b:v 288M -minrate 288M `
-maxrate 288M -bufsize 288M -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 384k -vsync 1 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 `
-f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_format_options max_delay=0 `
C:\Users\djcim\Videos\FFmpeg\CP\CP%02d.ts `
-map 2,1 -map 1 -c:v h264_nvenc -preset: llhp -r 25 -rc-lookahead 25 -pix_fmt nv12 -b:v 288M -minrate 288M `
-maxrate 288M -bufsize 288M -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 384k -vsync 1 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 `
-f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_format_options max_delay=0 `
C:\Users\djcim\Videos\FFmpeg\SB\SB%02d.ts `
-map 3:0,3:1 -map 3:1 -c:v h264_nvenc -preset: llhp -r 60 -rc-lookahead 60 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 288M -minrate 288M `
-maxrate 288M -bufsize 288M -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 384k -vsync 1 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 `
-f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_format_options max_delay=0 `
C:\Users\djcim\Videos\FFmpeg\EL\EL%02d.ts `
-map 4:0,4:1 -map 4:1 -c:v h264_nvenc -preset: llhp -r 60 -rc-lookahead 60 -pix_fmt nv12 -b:v 288M -minrate 288M `
-maxrate 288M -bufsize 288M -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 384k -vsync 1 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 `
-f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_format_options max_delay=0 `
C:\Users\djcim\Videos\FFmpeg\MW\MW%02d.ts `
-map 5:0,5:1 -map 5:1 -c:v h264_nvenc -preset: llhp -r 60 -rc-lookahead 60 -pix_fmt nv12 -b:v 288M -minrate 288M `
-maxrate 288M -bufsize 288M -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 192k -vsync 1 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 `
-f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_format_options max_delay=0 `
C:\Users\djcim\Videos\FFmpeg\AM\AM%02d.ts
```

This is also not to mention that the above command is a much more simplified version of what I actually use, I typically add a myriad of synchronization options to each output, but that isn't really relevant to its ability to transcode real time.

Any idea why the single file solution struggles while the latter does not? And if possible, a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing piece to the puzzle was -rc-lookahead which was omitted from the second command on my original post somehow.

If I add -rc-lookahead 60 to the multitrack file it fairly quickly gets up to realtime transcoding, example:

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147M -video_size 3840x2160 `
-framerate 60 -pixel_format nv12 -i video="Video (Pro Capture)":audio="ADAT (3+4) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147M -video_size 3840x2160 -framerate 60 -pixel_format nv12 `
-i video="AVerMedia HD Capture GC573 1":audio="Analog (1+2) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147M -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 60 -pixel_format yuv420p `
-i video="Game Capture HD60 Pro (Video) (#01)":audio="Game Capture HD60 Pro (Audio) (#01)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147M -i audio="ADAT (5+6) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2147M -i audio="SPDIF/ADAT (1+2) (RME Fireface UC)" `
-c:v h264_nvenc -preset: llhp -pix_fmt nv12 -rc-lookahead 60 -b:v 288M -minrate 288M -maxrate 288M -bufsize 288M -c:a aac `
-ar 44100 -b:a 384k -vsync 1 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -map 4 `
-f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_format_options max_delay=0 `
C:\Users\djcim\Videos\FFmpeg\FFmpeg%02d.ts
```

Comment: You may even decrease this value to 30 or lower, but it'll lead to decreased quality as well. This is a sort of "encoding buffer" where it looks at future frames to determine how to distribute the bits while encoding.

Comment: Does lowering the number theoretically increase transcoding speed? I put it up to 1000 and it didn't seem to make a difference, can't seem to find the min/max anywhere.

Comment: Theoretically yes, and the max/min is -1 to the biggest possible integer, but it'll be likely constrained by other settings like the length of a GOP. To be honest I don't know how NVENC implements it.